# where can I find the XML Schema for XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Does anyone have a working link to the XML Schema for XSLT 1.0 ? The 2 links from www.webmethods.com mentioned in http://sources.redhat.com/ml/xsl-list/2001-03/msg01405.html don't seem to refer to anything anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Try your local pc,

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\xslt.xsd`

Of course, install a MS VS 10.0 trial version first if you don't have it yet.